# Canvas ellipses all rotating to the same angle

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas, rotation, transform

I have a bubble field with elliptical bubbles. I'd like the bubbles to stretch -- elongate -- as they move to the edges of the canvas. This works on the sides, but top & bottom bubbles are getting flattened. I was trying to use atan2 to identify the angle and point that bubble's nose in that direction.

But when I add the rotation, all bubbles rotate. Is there a way to trap each bubble, calculate it's angle and rotate only that bubble instead of the whole context? `ctx.rotation` rotates the whole canvas. Makes sense. But `this.rotation` (currently commented out on line [149](https://codepen.io/theship/pen/NXQOVE) of my codepen) has all bubbles spinning the same.

```
bubble.prototype.draw = function(){  

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.save();


  var p1 = { x: 0, y: 0 };

  var p2 = { x: this.location.x, y: this.location.y };

  this.rotation = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x) * 180 / Math.PI;

  ctx.fillStyle = this.colour;
  ctx.ellipse(this.location.x, this.location.y, 
              this.radius, this.radiusY, 
              this.rotation, 
              0,360, 0);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.restore();
}
```

[Here's the whole codepen](https://codepen.io/theship/pen/NXQOVE?editors=1111)

Or maybe there's another way to radiate out shapes according to their radiant?

Comment: Rotation takes an angle as radians. Eg 0 to PI * 2 (0-360deg) you are setting the rotation as deg, just remove the conversion `180 / Math.PI` so the rotation is `this.rotation = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x)`

Comment: Thanks! That helped. But actually, I needed to move the code to the bubble class to stop the spinning. And when I used the velocity instead of the location, everything lined up!

Answer (score 0):

I moved the rotation calculation out of the`bubble.prototype.draw` and into the `bubble` function. Then, I took the velocity instead of the location and everything lined up!

```
var p2 = { x: this.velocity.x, y: this.velocity.y };
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/theship/pen/NXQOVE) updated!